# onDataChange() called twice if Double value in object set to 0 or 0.00

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Double value inside an object which I sync to Firebase using `setValue()`. The weird thing is that if the Double value is set to 0 or 0.00, the `onDataChange()` method gets called twice. I have replicated this hundred of times and can't seem to get my head it as to why it would do such thing. Is this a bug or am I going nuts?

I'm using the latest dependency which is 10.2.0.

Comment: A [MCVE] is always helpful.  Then we can not only see the code but copy and run it to try and duplicate the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem that exists when setting any double with a non-fractional decimal.  It has to do with the coercion of that double value to a long. It should be fixed in a future release of the SDK.